# Brackets with a center bracket

Tags: brackets

I have some data displayed in pairs. Currently, it appears like this, on one line:

```
(numbers; numbers; numbers)
```

However, I am looking for a better center divider. Here are some e.g.:

```
(numbers | numbers | numbers | numbers)
(numbers / numbers / numbers)
```

I am willing to change the outer brackets to any style, if necessary, to find a good match:

```
{numbers | numbers | numbers | numbers}
[numbers I numbers I numbers I numbers I numbers]
```

However, these all seem like good solutions. I cannot find any center divider that matches any of the outer dividers or that at least looks nice and visually separates the various parts.

What can I use?

Comment: I don't really understand what this question has to do with TeX or Friends? Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `\middle` command which provides extensible delimiters for the middle of a set of outer delimiters (like `\left` and `\right`). For example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left\{\frac{a}{b} \middle] \frac{c}{d} \middle| \frac{e}{f} \middle( \frac{g}{h} \right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

In the above example, the outer `\left` and `\right` pairs match, while the inner `\middle` macros do not have to match in number nor in delimiter usage. The latter, actually, also holds for the `\left` and `\right` pair.